# Next throwing an error when I make my component async

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, next.js, async-await

[image: Unhandled runtime error]

```js
export default async function StatsPage() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  let token: string = "";
  if (session?.user) {
    token = session?.user.data.auth_tokens["bearer-token"];
  }



  const data = await fetchVoiceCalls(token);
  console.log(data);

}

async function fetchVoiceCalls(token: string) {
  if (token) {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    };
    const res = await fetch(
      `end-point-here`,

      requestOptions
    );
    return "something";

    
}
```

I have tried resolving it like a promise but it leads unnecessary calls.
I also thought of using the new `use` hook but it seems to be experimental and I don't want to use it in application in production.

Comment: You should remove the `async` from your component, and call the `fetchVoiceCalls ` in `React.useEffect` once the token is resolved.

Comment: Okay, thanks it works. Will the fetch api be able to still revalidate, even though `fetchVoiceCalls` is being placed in a `useEffect`.

Comment: You are probably confusing client-side `fetch` with server-side `fetch`. For client-side fetch revalidation you probably want to use `swr` or `react-query`.

Comment: `async` is used only for server components

Comment: @IgorDanchenko I am kinda new to this. But I thought components are server components by default, so shouldn't my fetch should be a server-side fetch?

Comment: Make the component `async` throws the error in the image I've provided in the question. @Yilmaz

Comment: @sylvesterasa Are you using latest nextjs and app directory? Because your example is working

Comment: @sylvesterasa, your fetch is client-side because your StatsPage component is client-side. How do I know this? It can't be server-side because it's using client-side `useSession` hook. Even though the component itself doesn't have the "use client" magic, it must be rendered by another client component up in the hierarchy.

Comment: @VladVladov, I am on `next@13.3.4`, but my project is not using the `app` directory.

Comment: @IgorDanchenko, thanks, I have learnt something new. What do you mean by another client component?

Comment: @sylvesterasa you need to use app directory as server components are only in this new feature

Comment: @sylvesterasa, if your project is not using the app directory, then all your components are client components.